# Connecting to AWS instance with GUI

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm a PuTTY newbie. Sorry if my questions sounds a bit basic.

Our client has an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance to which we have received access. I can connect to the instance using PuTTY. But I need to install and test many programs and files on the instance.

I am wondering if one gets GUI access to an EC2 instance so one can use it like a normal OS and not through command line.

Comment: Ubuntu does not imply there is a GUI. And even if you “need to install and test many programs and files”, the command-line interface does not appear inappropriate to me. Unless those are GUI programs.

Comment: @DanielB no they are not GUI programs. but i honestly had no idea i'll be working in the dark and had therefore underestimated the amount of time needed. is it the same situation with a EC2 Windows instance.

Comment: You can connect to the same host using multiple PuTTY instances, by the way.

Comment: @DanielB thanks for answer. would you like to post it?

Comment: It’s not really an answer, because you *can* get GUI access using X11 forwarding or VNC or whatever. ;)

Comment: @DanielB well in that case would you post that as an answer?

Comment: @DanielB do X11 or VNC work with SSH?

Comment: *"so one can use it like a normal OS and not through command line"*  The argument could be made that this logic is exactly inverted, that the command line is "normal" access and using a GUI isn't.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot true. i meant if there's a GUI version of a remote server.